# lua substr - побитовый шаг

Tags: кодировка, lua

Есть ли у луа функция, которая работает так же как и mb_substr в php?
string.sub не подходит, т.к. там нет побитового шага.

Comment: думаю встроенного нет, раз люди библиотеки пишут https://github.com/starwing/luautf8

Comment: А как работает `mb_substr`? Или вы думаете, что все знают php? Вы бы лучше описали проблему, которую пытаетесь решить.

Comment: @Mike В lua 5.3 есть базовая поддержка utf-8, а та библиотека - бэкпорт в 5.1 и 5.2.

Comment: @zed тогда напишите ответ. mb_substr в php это версия substr получающая часть строки по количеству utf8 символов, а не байт

Comment: string mb_substr (string str, int start [, int length [, string encoding]])

mb_substr() возвращает часть строки str, специфицированную параметрами start и length.

Comment: Проблема в том что данные которые я получаю от php, применяя побитовый шаг -  mb_substr($value 32, 16,**'8bit'**) - возвращают мне правильное значение, а вот луа, возвращает не верное значения.
если в php убрать 4 параметр(8bit)-то значение так же будет не верное.

Answer (score 0):

В lua 5.3 можно воспользоваться таким алгоритмом:

1. Воспользоваться функцией [utf8.offset](http://q-syshelp.qschome.com/Content/Control%20Scripting/Lua%205.3%20Reference%20Manual/Standard%20Libraries/4%20-%20Basic%20UTF-8%20Support.htm) и найти позицию (байт) символа с которого надо начать копировать;
2. Той же функцией найти позицию символа до которого надо скопировать;
3. Воспользоваться стандартной функцией `string.sub`, которая копирует побайтово.

Пример (сохранить в файл, в кодировке UTF-8):

```
s = 'Юникодная строка';

i = utf8.offset(s, 11);
j = utf8.offset(s, 17);

s1 = string.sub(s, i, j);

print(s1);
```

Напечатает:

```
строка
```

---

Если же попытаться скопировать в лоб, с 11 по 17 байт:

```
s2 = string.sub(s, 11, 17);
```

то в `s2` окажется "мусор":

```
дна\209
```

Comment: У меня строка выглядит следующим образом:
$J�R[Tߑ��ǢN�m3�d�@�;@���+m��Q�8�os�E��~8f124d90c959e36d81464‌​562fe0393e2

Comment: @smilexcasper И что? Если это utf-8, то указанный в ответе способ будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ от zed будет некорректным, если конец подстроки - это знак Unicode, и её конец не совпадает с концом строки (попытайтесь вырезать "код")

[В рассылке Lua](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2014-04/msg00590.html) был предоставлен более корректный код:

```
function utf8sub(s,i,j)
   i = i or 1
   j = j or -1
   if i<1 or j<1 then
      local n = utf8.len(s)
      if not n then return nil end
      if i<0 then i = n+1+i end
      if j<0 then j = n+1+j end
      if i<0 then i = 1 elseif i>n then i = n end
      if j<0 then j = 1 elseif j>n then j = n end
   end
   if j<i then return "" end
   i = utf8.offset(s,i)
   j = utf8.offset(s,j+1)
   if i and j then return s:sub(i,j-1)
      elseif i then return s:sub(i)
      else return ""
   end
end
```

Тем не менее, и он не является полностью правильным, т.к. например не учитывает графемы из Unicode.